# Add an integer to a class atribute

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this simple class, with 3 atributes Name Surname and Birth year, and as I define an object of this class, instead of receive the Birth Year I want the age of the person.

```
class Person:
   def __init__(self,Fname,Lname,Byear):
       self.firtsName = Fname
       self.lastName = Lname
       self.birth_year = Byear
   def __str__(self):
        return '{}, {} Age:{}'.format(self.firtsName,self.lastName,self.birth_year)
p1=Person('Olivia','Parker','1985')
print(p1)
```

I want to subtract the current year to the birth year, using this 
`import date from datetime

current_year=date.today().year`

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you were trying to do:

```
>>> class Person:
...    def __init__(self,Fname,Lname,Byear):
...        self.firtsName = Fname
...        self.lastName = Lname
...        self.birth_year = Byear
...    def __str__(self):
...        return "%s, %s Age: %s" %(self.lastName, self.firtsName, (datetime.datetime.now().year-self.birth_year))
... 
>>> p1=Person('Olivia','Parker',1985)
>>> print(p1)
Parker, Olivia Age: 28
```

Keep in mind though, that this won't take into account some nuances like "it's now January 2014 and  was born in October 1985)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want [property](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) ?

```
from datetime import date

class Person:
    def __init__(self, fname, lname, byear):
        self.first_name = fname
        self.last_name = lname
        self.birth_year = byear

    @property
    def age(self):
        return date.today().year - self.birth_year

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0.first_name}, {0.last_name} Age:{0.age}'.format(self)

p1 = Person('Olivia', 'Parker', 1985)
print(p1)
```

prints

```
Olivia, Parker Age:28
```

BTW, the code is mixing use of `lower_case_with_underscores`, `mixedCase` for attributes. Choose one. See [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code -- Descriptive: Naming Styles](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles).